# Using Jquery with .asp pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem with Jquery and Javascript in .asp pages.
It seems Jquery not working at all.

I insert a flip card with 2 images. On html pages that work fine but as soon I insert it in .asp page that not work anymore.

This is my code :

```
<!-- #include file="../_include/config.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="../_include/fonctions.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="../_include/check_connect.asp" -->
<%
chapitre="cartesmemo"
page="index.asp"


%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<title><%=GetTexte("titrePage")%></title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--JS flip -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="flip-master/dist/jquery.flip.js"></script>


<!--css flip-->


<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="../_include/commun.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../_include/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Police Marydale pour la version smartphone -->
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/sgh1xfn.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>




<!-- début js flip  --> 



</head>
<!--  ici, dans le body on indique dans la page si c'est minutes ou autres pour avoir le bon fond, les bonnes couleurs de titre, de puces et de picto (attention juste au picto à génerer en fonction de la rubrique) -->

<body class="fondmemo">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"> 
    <!-- sidebar navigation gauche  -->
    <nav class="navbar col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar"> 

      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header"><a href="<%=home_path&"home.asp"%>"><img src="../_images/logo-my.png" width="144" height="96" alt="logo my.doit" class="hidden-xs"></a>
        <div class="logo">my.doit.network</div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
        <!-- #include file="../menu.asp" --> 

      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- fin sidebar  navigation gauche  --> 

    <!-- page principale   -->
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-md-offset-3 main">
      <div class="row titre">
        <h1><%=GetTexte("titrePage")%></h1>
      </div>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="<%=home_path&"home.asp"%>"><%=GetTexte("fil_ariane1")%></a></li>
        <li class="active"><%=GetTexte("fil_ariane2")%></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- page principale   -->

      <div class="row pageblanche">
        <div class="pictotitre" style="float:left"> 
          <!-- ici on indique le bon picto  de rubrique  -->
          <div class="rond center-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
        </div>
        <!-- fin picto   -->

        <h2>Nom de la carte</h2>
        <div class="row contenupageblanche">

<div id="notice" class="row col-md-12">
<p class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt text-uppercase" style="font-size:12px"> Cliquez sur la carte mémo pour voir son verso</p>
</div> 

<div class="center-slider col-md-12">

<!--début flip-->
<div class="flip">
  <div class="front"><img src="img/superheroes-cartes-flash-green-lantern.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="back"><img src="img/superheroes-cartes-postales-batman-robin.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<!--fin flip-->

</div>      

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fin page principale   --> 

  </div>
  <!-- fin row   --> 

</div>
<!-- fin container  --> 
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".flip").flip({
        trigger: 'click'
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
<!-- #include file="../_include/close.asp" -->
```

I really don't see the point of this.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

see the console of the browser. see the jquery file is not giving 404 error.

Comment: It can be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Thanks for help, there's no 404 error in the console. but I have this error message : **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).liquidSlider is not a function**

Comment: sorry i cant make a comment since my reptutation is low

Comment: You meen I link an older version of jQuery ?

Comment: have you add liquid slider jquery file in your page?

Comment: i couldnt find it

Comment: Really sorry, I've mistake with another error log. the error in the console is : https://my.doit.network/cartesmemo/flip-master/dist/jquery.flip.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I use the liquid slider for another pahe that not work also. I have the same problem on both pages. The Jquery plugins not work....

Comment: jquery 3.1.1 is the worst jquery library i've ever seen. first of all make sure all the files are loaded no 404 error and then try to use other jquery version if you are using 3.1.1

Comment: and also make sure you add jquery compatible liquidSlider ... it has usually .jquery.js at the end

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. The files are well added. But it's true I have a 404 error message. I just don't understand why 404 error

Comment: The error message I have left is : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).liquidSlider is not a function

Comment: one of you js files are not loaded

Comment: I have no 404 error any more. The error now is that the flip function is not recognized.... You mean the flip function is not recognize because one of my js file not loaded ?

Comment: see you use liquidslider in your js and you need jquery.liquid-slider.js which is compatible with jquery